# c# streamwriter datagrid.backcolor write *txt

Tags: c#

```
StreamWriter dosya = File.AppendText(yol);
dosya.Write(comboBox1.Text + "*");
dosya.Write(txtLikitadi.Text + "*");
dosya.Write(textBox3.Text + "*");
dosya.Write(textBox1.Text + "*");
dosya.Write(lblAroma.Text + "*");
dosya.Write(lblBase.Text + "*");
dosya.Write(lblGliserin.Text + "*");
dosya.WriteLine(lblPG.Text + "*");
dosya.Close();
liste();
```

I am transferring information from the program to a text file.

How can I add datagridview currentrow backcolor information this text ?

then I'll split it up and get this info

Thanks

Comment: How would you set the backcolor in design time..? then assign a variable to that selected rows background color..? have you even tried looking at the properties of the DataGrid..?

Comment: Please reconsider your programming style. What happens if someone types an asterisk into `txtLikitadi`? Why use `*` as a separator and not save the data in a common file format like XML or JSON?

Comment: I'm more new.
First background color White
In short, what I want to do is actually;

Change background color through a button and save it to a .txt file.
But since I have recorded the records at the beginning,
I do not know how I do after.

Comment: For example my txt files

6 MG*RELAX*500*10*50*300*150*0* 

i want 
6 MG*RELAX*500*10*50*300*150*0*GREEN*

Comment: i use "*" because 
then I'll split it up and get this info

   while (oku != null) //oku farklıysa boştan
                {
                    string[] parca = oku.Split('*');
                    dgkayitlar.Rows.Add(parca[0], parca[1],parca[2], parca[3], parca[4], parca[5], parca[6], parca[7]);
                    oku = dosya.ReadLine();
                }

Comment: @BuğraTekin I would suggest that you do a simple google search, there are actually working examples on what to do.. since you refuse to show us what you have actually tried..

Comment: @MethodMan I can transfer the entire program here if necessary, but if I know how to do this, I can do it myself.
Sorry if we made a mistake.
I searched but I wrote here because I could not find it.

Comment: what key word are you searching on can you show us? perhaps you are doing google searches incorrectly

Comment: @MethodMan i know this 

secilisatir = dgkayitlar.CurrentRow.Index;
dgkayitlar.Rows[secilisatir].Cells[i].Style.BackColor = Color.Green 

but i dont know write to txt backcolor information ..

Comment: Ok @BuğraTekin, do a google search on the `Color.ToString()`

Answer (score 0):

The term back color is ambiguous. Back colors can be set on the whole grid, a row and even on individual cells. All of the following might be valid answers, depending on what you're talking about:

```
dosya.Write(dataGridView1.RowsDefaultCellStyle.BackColor);
dosya.Write(datagridview1.CurrentRow.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor);
dosya.Write(datagridview1.CurrentRow.Cells[0].Style.BackColor);
```